# Excel Formula: check if any cell in a range is not empty and not contain specific text

Tags: excel-formula

Trying get a formula that would return true if any of cell in A1:A7 range has anything (text, numbers, references, etc), as long as it's NOT string "blah" or "halb".

Comment: This is not an excel formula.

Comment: @Scott Craner: How's so? What is it then?

Comment: `ARRAYFORMULA` is not Excel it is Google SpreadSheets.

Comment: Well, sorry, I was testing it in google sheets, it works in Excel 2000 the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=0<SUMPRODUCT((A1:A7<>"")*(A1:A7<>"blah")*(A1:A7<>"halb"))
```

Basically it counts the number of non blank cells, and it only counts the cells that do not equal blah or halb.  the final check is if the count is 0 or greater than 0 in order to get a true or false result.

Comment: This works great, per original description. But fails on numbered values. I've updated my original description to reflect that.

Comment: Updated to reflect updated question.  The check if it was text was removed

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
=IF(COUNTA(A1:A7)=0,FALSE,IF(COUNTA(A1:A7)=COUNTIF(A1:A7,"BLAH")+COUNTIF(A1:A7,"HALB"),FALSE,TRUE))
```